# <ul> bleeding out of <nav>

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

So I've got a problem here that is especially frustrating considering I'm creating a simple navbar. I've searched high and low for a solution to no avail so hopefully you guys can shine a light on this. What is happening is that the  with all of my  tags in it is not even displaying inside the navbar it's quite literally moving outside the container and not even display:inline-block; is working in this case. Hope you guys can help me.

```css
nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 28%;

}
nav ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

nav #logo{
    width: 30%;
}

nav #logo img{
    width: 80%;
}

nav a{
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:link{
    color: black;
}
nav a:hover{
    border-bottom: solid black .1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="comp6.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><p>Home</p></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><p>About Us</p></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><p>Services</p></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><p>Blog</p></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><p>Works</p></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><p>Contacts</p></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your li-elements are float left so setting a height for them should help you out.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

To make it all line up nicely, try this

```
nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul li{
    margin-left: 3%;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav #logo{
    float: left;
}

nav #logo img{
    width: 80%;
}

nav a{
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:link{
    color: black;
}
nav a:hover{
    border-bottom: solid black .1em;
}
nav p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sqzvkosp/1/

Comment: Sorry guys but none of these solutions are what I need. What needs to happen is for the ul element with all of the links to set directly beside the logo. Instead the ul is pushed outside of the nav. I still haven't found a fix

Comment: Does this answer your needs? http://jsfiddle.net/sqzvkosp/1/ If it does, I can update the answer so it can be marked

Comment: Updated the answer so you can mark it as solved if it helped you =)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what is mandatory for you i tried this way you can modify following as per your need

```css
/*nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 28%;

}
nav ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

nav #logo{
    width: 30%;
}

nav #logo img{
    width: 80%;
}

nav a{
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:link{
    color: black;
}
nav a:hover{
    border-bottom: solid black .1em;
}

/****** new styles ********/

nav {
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* height: 5em; */
    /* float: left; */
    display: block;
}
nav #logo {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    /* width: 28%; */
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 3%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Works</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

here i am providing this working code of my try 
[My demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/b0dcj3x3/2/)

Comment: @Trenton May please check out the answer'